# What does tie-breaking mean?

Tags: java, priority-queue

I'm reading about PriorityQueues in javadocs and it mentions the term tie-breaking. I couldn't undersand what does the term mean. I hope someone could explain.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiebreaker

Comment: @JonSkeet: I saw that too.  Referring to a sports metaphor is unlikely to be illuminating, especially if the user's second language is English.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I disagree - I think within the context of the documentation ("The head of this queue is the least element with respect to the specified ordering. If multiple elements are tied for least value, the head is one of those elements -- ties are broken arbitrarily") the wikipedia summary ("In games and sports, a tiebreaker or tiebreak is used to determine a winner from among players or teams that are tied at the end of a contest, or a set of contests") should be enough to work out the meaning.

Answer (score 10):

In Java, comparison is done using a `compare(a,b)` method (for comparators) or `a.compareTo(b)` method (for class instances that can be compared). This method is supposed to return a negative number whenever `a < b`, a positive number when `a > b`, and `0` when `a = b`.

However sometimes people just use return value `0` to mean `a` and `b` are incomparable (some orderings aren't total).  In this case, the `PriorityQueue` has to decide which element goes first. This is tie-breaking. Specifically some priority queues preserve the order in which zero-comparing elements were inserted, so in that case insertion time is the tie-breaker.  Then for a collection of elements where `compareTo()` always returns `0`, the priority queue would act just like a normal queue.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a priority Que that uses Node.Score to assign priority, if two scores are the same you have a tie.

You could implement first-in-first-out tie-breaking to comparable elements.  If two scores are the same the priority is given to the node that was added first.

```
if(NodeA.getScore() == NodeB.getScore()){
    //this is a tie
    if(NodeA.getOrderAdded() > NodeB.GetOrderAdded(){
        //NodeA has priority
    } else {
        //NodeB has priority
    }
}
```